# Katib experiment not able to access GCS bucket due to insufficient permissions

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubeflow

I m trying to run kubeflow pipeline from Google Cloud Build on a Kubeflow cluster as part of Continous Deployment.

I have created a service account and given access to GCS bucket.

In the Kubeflow pipeline, I am applying service account's user-gcp-sa to all pipeline steps. The first step in the pipeline is launching a katib experiment in kubeflow namespace. However, the experiment fails with below reason.

The flow is this:
Cloud build triggers a python file that creates a KFP client and then uses the client to upload the pipeline and run a experiment.

First pipeline step launches a katib experiment and waits for it to finish. The experiment is launched successfully and pods are created for running the trials, however pods then fail with below reason and experiment fails overall.

**message: "Primary: /namespaces/<project_id>.svc.id.goog with additional claims does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object."**

If I give allUsers access to GCS bucket, the experiment works fine.

I have also followed below link for troubleshooting -
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity

I have few questions on this -

1. Which service account is being used to access the GCS bucket from inside katib experiment ?
2. How to fix the above issue?

Any troubleshooting steps will be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the **message** is pointing to the user that you are authenticated with within your containers and that user doesn't have the permissions needed to access the GCS bucket.

The **"<project_id>.svc.id.goog"** is the Workload Identity Namespace created when you enable Workload Identity in your GKE cluster. **Workload Identity** is intended to configure a Kubernetes service account (**KSA**) to act as a Google service account (**GSA**). in order to get authenticated within your pods with the GSA, you will need to create all the pods that are intended to perform operation in GCS within the specified **K8s_namespace** and with the **KSA** you configured whith Workload identity, this will automatically create the bind from your **KSA** to your **GSA** within your containers.

Be assured that the **GSA** has the correct permission to access the bucket such as **Storage Admin** which includes all storage permissions, here the [predefined permissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#standard-roles) and the [different bucket permissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-permissions#bucket_permissions).

As this [link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity) mentions you will need to create a **GSA**, **KSA** and **k8s-namespace**, these 3 resources will create the bind for auth externally as a **GSA** but internally (within your cluster) as a **KSA**.

**In case you do not remember the k8s-namespace, KSA and GSA you configured in Workload Identity then try to follow next:**

1. Get into your GKE cluster and find for a Namespace different of:

default
kube-node-lease
kube-public
kube-system

Use command `kubectl get ns` to get the Namespaces, here an example of the output:

```
gilbertoa@cloudshell:~ (Project_ID)$ kubectl get ns
NAME              STATUS   AGE
default           Active   25d
kube-node-lease   Active   25d
kube-public       Active   25d
kube-system       Active   25d
wlins             Active   25d
```

**In this case I do remember that the k8s_namespace I configured in Workload Identity is `wlins`**

2. Check the service account within the identified Namespace:

Use command  `kubectl get sa -n IDENTIFIED_NAMESPACE`, here an example of the output:

```
gilbertoa@cloudshell:~ (Project_ID)$ kubectl get sa -n wlins
NAME      SECRETS   AGE
default   1         25d
wlisa     1         25d
```

**In this case I do remember that the KSA I configured in Workload Identity is `wlisa`**

3. Check for the KSA annotation made during Workload Identity configuration:

Use command  `kubectl describe sa YOUR_KSA -n IDENTIFIED_NAMESPACE`, here an example of the output:

```
gilbertoa@cloudshell:~ (Project_ID)$ kubectl describe sa wlisa -n wlins
Name:                wlisa
Namespace:           wlins
Labels:              <none>
Annotations:         iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account: wli-sa@Project_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com
Image pull secrets:  <none>
Mountable secrets:   wlisa-token-8jpq2
Tokens:              wlisa-token-8jpq2
Events:              <none>
```

**In this case I do remember that the GSA I configured in Workload Identity is `wli-sa@project_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com`**

4. Validation...

By running next command, which is on the step 9 of the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity#enable_on_new_cluster) you shared, and substituting the `ksa-name` and `k8s-namespace`

```
kubectl run -it \
  --image google/cloud-sdk:slim \
  --serviceaccount ksa-name \
  --namespace k8s-namespace \
  workload-identity-test
```

Here is the test I did:

```
  gilbertoa@cloudshell:~ (Project_ID)$ **kubectl run -it \
    >   --image google/cloud-sdk:slim \
    >   --serviceaccount wlisa \
    >   --namespace wlins \
    >   workload-identity-test**
    If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
```

Here is the container interface I got automatically with above command and where you can see that the active account is the GSA I configured in Workload Identity:

```
root@workload-identity-test:/#
root@workload-identity-test:/# gcloud auth list
                Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
*       wli-sa@Project_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com
To set the active account, run:
    $ gcloud config set account `ACCOUNT`
root@workload-identity-test:/#
```

**Lastly. If you use a different **KSA** and **k8s_namespace** to create your pods/containers then you will not be authenticated as the GSA**

Here is the command I used, where I'm not using any **KSA** and using a different **k8s_namespace** (default namespace). When I checked the active account it shows the Workload Identity **Project_ID.svc.id.goog** Namespace, which doesn't have any IAM permissions and if I try to update a bucket I will get a permission denied message.

```
gilbertoa@cloudshell:~ (Project_ID)$   kubectl run -it \
>   --image google/cloud-sdk:slim \
>   --namespace default \
>   workload-identity-test-bad

root@workload-identity-test-bad:/# gcloud auth list
      Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
*       Project_ID.svc.id.goog
To set the active account, run:
    $ gcloud config set account `ACCOUNT`
root@workload-identity-test-bad:/#
```

I know it was a long response, but I hope this can help you somehow to fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably just need to add the following to the Pod spec in the Job template inside your Katib Experiment

```
...
spec:
  serviceAccountName: default-editor
  ...
```

Background: the "default-editor" serviceaccount is explicitly created in every user namespace by Kubeflow, to allow access to GCP APIs such as Google Cloud Storage via Workload Identity, but it is not the default serviceaccount for all pods. The detailed answer by Ariel Palacios helped me figure this out.